# How to not deliver results for long running task if "source" observables change

Tags: rx-java, rx-java2

I am triggering a long-running CPU-intensive task by populating some observers and I'm having trouble determining if I'm setting things up properly.

Ideally, my requirements are:

- Trigger the task when all 3 of my BehaviorSubjects are populated (and then each time any one of them changes)
- Only run one calculation at a time
- Don't deliver a calculated result that is "out-of-date" due to the source triggers changing

My current solution is this, but I'm not sure if it is the best way to do it. Particularly, the "version" variable seems wrong. Also, it seems wrong having to specify an `observeOn` in my chain, but I know that is a side effect of me using BehaviorSubject.

```
    final AtomicInteger version = new AtomicInteger(0);
    return Observable.combineLatest(
                mBehaviorSubjectArg1,
                mBehaviorSubjectArg2,
                mBehaviorSubjectArg3,
                (arg1, arg2, arg3) -> new Arguments(version.incrementAndGet(), arg1, arg2, arg3)
            )
            // Only keep the latest combination so when observeOn pulls we don't run interim data points
            .toFlowable(BackpressureStrategy.LATEST)
            // Only buffer 1 so we don't ask for additional arguments until we have completed the last computation. 
            .observeOn(Schedulers.computation(), false, 1)
            .map(args -> new Pair<>(args, mCalculator.run(args)))
            .filter(pair -> pair.first.version == version.get())
            .map(pair -> pair.second);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems like the perfect example where the `switchMap` operator would work. If you can change `mCalculator.run(args)` to return an Observable (potentially allowing for cancellation if `Observable.create` and `ObservableEmitter.setCancellable` are used) then the following code would work:

```
return Observable.combineLatest(
            mBehaviorSubjectArg1,
            mBehaviorSubjectArg2,
            mBehaviorSubjectArg3,
            (arg1, arg2, arg3) -> new Arguments(arg1, arg2, arg3)
        ).switchMap((args) -> mCalculator.run(args).subscribeOn(Schedulers.computation()))
```

The `switchMap` will ensure only the latest `Arguments` instance will be running concurrently, cancelling the Observable if a new instance is emitted by the `combineLatest`. The `subscribeOn` within the `switchMap` is there to ensure no deadlock can occur due to a mistake in `mCalculator.run`

Comment: It did seem like switchMap was potentially the right choice here. So, as far as my requirements go, the "only run one a time" would only be semi guaranteed based on how well I can implement cancellation within my calculator? In other words, I know switchMap will prevent any old data from coming in, but the actual calculation obviously won't stop until I can handle the cancelled flag. Also, what kind of mistakes could I make in mCalculator.run that I would have to worry about. Bonus question: How would I pass an empty calculation result every time the switchMap is triggered. A doOnNext maybe?

Comment: As long as you  use one of the factory methods on `Observable` to implement `mCalculator.run` there shouldnt be any major issues. You could pass an empty result every time `switchMap` changes by adding `.startWith(Object)` to the inner observable, so it emits that value before beginning the calculation each time.

Comment: Thanks for the help. So just to be clear though, every new argument instance will trigger a new calculation, but i will just rely on cancellation signals to stop them?

Comment: Yup, `switchMap` will ensure only one Observable will be observed at once.